# Separation of concerns for security checks

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, generics

I needed a nice typesafe way to implement security checks for various domain objects and actions that can be performed on them.

I had an idea how to do it, so I implemented it as a simple proof of concept.

The core is the `ActionSelector<,>` class that receives two objects, `securityChecker` that checks for security, and `endpointFactory` which is used to create real endpoint for action.
Both `securityChecker` and `endpointFactory` implement generic interface which defines a list of possible actions.
`securityChecker` implementation specifies `T` as `SecurityCheckResult` and  `endpointFactory` specifies `T` as `HtmlEndpoint`.
ActionSelector takes in same generic interface, but with `T` as an object. If the `securityChecker` passes, the result from `endpointFactory` is returned. If it does not pass, it uses `disabledEndpointFactory` to return disabled endpoint representation.

```
public class ActionSelector<TFormat, TCommonInterface>
{
    private readonly Action<TCommonInterface> initalize;
    private readonly TCommonInterface securityChecker;
    private readonly TCommonInterface endpointFactory;
    private readonly IDisabledEndpointFactory<TFormat> disabledEndpointFactory;

    public ActionSelector(
        IDisabledEndpointFactory<TFormat> disabledEndpointFactory,
        TCommonInterface securityChecker,
        TCommonInterface endpointFactory,
        Action<TCommonInterface> initialize)
    {
        this.initalize = initialize;
        this.disabledEndpointFactory = disabledEndpointFactory;
        this.securityChecker = securityChecker;
        this.endpointFactory = endpointFactory;
    }

    public bool IsActionAllowed(Func<TCommonInterface, Func<object>> methodSelector)
    {
        this.initalize(securityChecker);
        var performSecurityCheck = methodSelector(securityChecker);
        return ((SecurityCheckResult) performSecurityCheck()).Allowed;
    }

    public TFormat Action(Func<TCommonInterface, Func<object>> methodSelector)
    {
        if (IsActionAllowed(methodSelector))
        {
            this.initalize(this.endpointFactory);
            var generateActionInvocation = methodSelector(this.endpointFactory);
            return (TFormat) generateActionInvocation();
        }
        else
        {
            return disabledEndpointFactory.Create();
        }
    }
}

public interface IDisabledEndpointFactory<out T>
{
    T Create();
}

public class SecurityCheckResult
{
    public static readonly SecurityCheckResult Ok = new SecurityCheckResult(true);

    public static readonly SecurityCheckResult Fail = new SecurityCheckResult(false);

    public SecurityCheckResult(bool allowed)
    {
        this.Allowed = allowed;
    }

    public bool Allowed { get; private set; }
}
```

This is a helper class that creates selectors for specific `securityChecker` and `endpointFactory` setups.

```
public class ActionEndpointFactory<TFormat>
{
    private readonly IDisabledEndpointFactory<TFormat> disabledEndpointFactory;

    public ActionEndpointFactory(IDisabledEndpointFactory<TFormat> disabledEndpointFactory)
    {
        this.disabledEndpointFactory = disabledEndpointFactory;
    }

    public ActionSelector<TFormat, TCommonInterface> CreateActionSelector<TCommonInterface>(
        TCommonInterface endpointFactory,
        TCommonInterface securityChecker,
        Action<TCommonInterface> init)
    {
        return new ActionSelector<TFormat, TCommonInterface>(this.disabledEndpointFactory,
            securityChecker, endpointFactory, init);
    }
}
```

Action interfaces are defined like this:

```
public interface IActions<out T>
    where T : class
{
    T Create();
    T Read();
    T Update();
    T Delete();
}

public interface IInvoiceActions<out T> : IActions<T>
    where T : class
{
    IContext Context { get; set; }

    Invoice Invoice { get; set; }

    T Publish();

    T Unpublish();

    T Send();

    T Cancel();
}

public interface IInvoiceItemActions<out T> : IActions<T>
    where T : class
{
    IContext Context { get; set; }

    Invoice Invoice { get; set; }

    InvoiceItem Item { get; set; }

    T SetPrice();

    T RemoveVAT();
}
```

Here are the classes representing endpoints for HTML (not real implementation).

```
public class HtmlEndpoint
{
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public object RouteValues { get; set; }

    public virtual string RenderAsButton(string text)
    {
        return "<button>" + text + "</button>";
    }

    public virtual string RenderAsImage(string src)
    {
        return "<img src=\"" + src + "\"/>";
    }
}

public class DisabledHtmlEndpointFactory : IDisabledEndpointFactory<HtmlEndpoint>
{
    private class DisabledHtmlEndpoint : HtmlEndpoint
    {
        public override string RenderAsImage(string src)
        {
            return "<img class=\"disabled\" src=\"" + src + "\" />";
        }

        public override string RenderAsButton(string text)
        {
            return "<span class=\"disabled button\">" + text + "</span>";
        }
    }

    public HtmlEndpoint Create()
    {
        return new DisabledHtmlEndpoint();
    }
}
```

Concrete implementation of security check for Invoice and InvoiceItem entities:

```
public class InvoiceSecurity : DatabaseSecurity, IInvoiceActions<SecurityCheckResult>
{
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }

    public InvoiceSecurity()
        : base(DomainObjects.Invoice)
    {
    }

    public override SecurityCheckResult Update()
    {
        return Result(this.Invoice.InvoiceID >= 0 &&
                      this.Invoice.CompanyID == Context.CompanyID &&
                      base.Update().Allowed);
    }

    public override SecurityCheckResult Delete()
    {
        return Result(this.Invoice.Status == InvoiceStatus.Draft &&
                      this.Invoice.CompanyID == Context.CompanyID &&
                      base.Delete().Allowed);
    }

    public SecurityCheckResult Publish()
    {
        return Result(this.Invoice.Status == InvoiceStatus.Draft &&
                      this.Invoice.CompanyID == Context.CompanyID &&
                      this.Update().Allowed);
    }

    public SecurityCheckResult Unpublish()
    {
        return Result(this.Invoice.Status == InvoiceStatus.NotSent &&
                      this.Invoice.CompanyID == Context.CompanyID &&
                      this.Update().Allowed);
    }

    public SecurityCheckResult Send()
    {
        return Result(this.Invoice.Status == InvoiceStatus.NotSent &&
                      this.Context.IsAdminLoggedIn() &&
                      this.Update().Allowed);
    }

    public SecurityCheckResult Cancel()
    {
        return Result(this.Invoice.Status != InvoiceStatus.Paid &&
                      this.Invoice.Status != InvoiceStatus.Cancelled &&
                      this.Invoice.CompanyID == Context.CompanyID &&
                      this.Context.IsAdminLoggedIn() &&
                      this.Update().Allowed);
    }
}

public class InvoiceItemSecurity : DatabaseSecurity, IInvoiceItemActions<SecurityCheckResult>
{
    private readonly InvoiceSecurity invoiceSecurity;

    public InvoiceItemSecurity() : base(DomainObjects.InvoiceItem)
    {
        this.invoiceSecurity = new InvoiceSecurity();
    }

    public Invoice Invoice
    {
        get { return invoiceSecurity.Invoice; }
        set { invoiceSecurity.Invoice = value; }
    }

    public override IContext Context
    {
        get { return invoiceSecurity.Context; }
        set { invoiceSecurity.Context = value; }
    }

    public InvoiceItem Item { get; set; }

    public SecurityCheckResult SetPrice()
    {
        return invoiceSecurity.Update();
    }

    public SecurityCheckResult RemoveVAT()
    {
        return invoiceSecurity.Update();
    }
}
```

Concrete implementation of Html endpoints for Invoice and InvoiceItem:

```
public class InvoiceHtmlActions : IInvoiceActions<HtmlEndpoint>
{
    public IContext Context { get; set; }

    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }

    public int InvoiceID
    {
        get { return Invoice.InvoiceID; }
    }

    public HtmlEndpoint Create()
    {
        return new HtmlEndpoint
        {
            Controller = "Invoice",
            Action = "Upsert",
            RouteValues = new { parentId = Context.CompanyID }
        };
    }

    public HtmlEndpoint Read()
    {
        return new HtmlEndpoint
        {
            Controller = "Invoice",
            Action = "Get",
            RouteValues = new { entityId = InvoiceID }
        };
    }

    public HtmlEndpoint Update()
    {
        return new HtmlEndpoint
        {
            Controller = "Invoice",
            Action = "Upsert",
            RouteValues = new { entityId = InvoiceID }
        };
    }

    public HtmlEndpoint Delete()
    {
        return new HtmlEndpoint
        {
            Controller = "Invoice",
            Action = "Delete",
            RouteValues = new { entityId = InvoiceID }
        };
    }

    public HtmlEndpoint Publish()
    {
        return new HtmlEndpoint
        {
            Controller = "Invoice",
            Action = "Publish",
            RouteValues = new { entityId = InvoiceID }
        };
    }

    public HtmlEndpoint Unpublish()
    {
        return new HtmlEndpoint
        {
            Controller = "Invoice",
            Action = "Unpublish",
            RouteValues = new { entityId = InvoiceID }
        };
    }

    public HtmlEndpoint Send()
    {
        return new HtmlEndpoint
        {
            Controller = "Invoice",
            Action = "Send",
            RouteValues = new { entityId = InvoiceID }
        };
    }

    public HtmlEndpoint Cancel()
    {
        return new HtmlEndpoint
        {
            Controller = "Invoice",
            Action = "Cancel",
            RouteValues = new { entityId = InvoiceID }
        };
    }
}

public class InvoiceItemHtmlActions : Domain.Actions.IInvoiceItemActions<HtmlEndpoint>
{
    public IContext Context { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public InvoiceItem Item { get; set; }

    public HtmlEndpoint Create()
    {
        return new HtmlEndpoint
        {
            Controller = "InvoiceItem",
            Action = "Upsert",
            RouteValues = new { parentId = Invoice.InvoiceID }
        };
    }

    public HtmlEndpoint Read()
    {
        return new HtmlEndpoint
        {
            Controller = "InvoiceItem",
            Action = "Get",
            RouteValues = new { entityId = Item.InvoiceItemID }
        };
    }

    public HtmlEndpoint Update()
    {
        return new HtmlEndpoint
        {
            Controller = "InvoiceItem",
            Action = "Upsert",
            RouteValues = new { entityId = Item.InvoiceItemID }
        };
    }

    public HtmlEndpoint Delete()
    {
        return new HtmlEndpoint
        {
            Controller = "InvoiceItem",
            Action = "Delete",
            RouteValues = new { entityId = Item.InvoiceItemID }
        };
    }

    public HtmlEndpoint SetPrice()
    {
        return new HtmlEndpoint
        {
            Controller = "InvoiceItem",
            Action = "SetPrice",
            RouteValues = new { entityId = Item.InvoiceItemID }
        };
    }

    public HtmlEndpoint RemoveVAT()
    {
        return new HtmlEndpoint
        {
            Controller = "InvoiceItem",
            Action = "RemoveVAT",
            RouteValues = new { entityId = Item.InvoiceItemID }
        };
    }
}
```

Finally, a class implementing `ActionEndpointFactory<>` which is responsible for setting up the configurations for all the entity classes.

```
public class InvoicingEndpointFactory<TFormat> : ActionEndpointFactory<TFormat>
    where TFormat : class
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope scope;

    public InvoicingEndpointFactory(ILifetimeScope scope)
        : base(scope.Resolve<IDisabledEndpointFactory<TFormat>>())
    {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public ActionSelector<TFormat, IInvoiceActions<object>> ForInvoice(IContext context, Invoice invoice)
    {
        return CreateActionSelector<IInvoiceActions<object>>(
            scope.Resolve<IInvoiceActions<TFormat>>(),
            new InvoiceSecurity(),
            i =>
            {
                i.Context = context;
                i.Invoice = invoice;
            });
    }

    public ActionSelector<TFormat, IInvoiceItemActions<object>> ForInvoiceItem(IContext context, InvoiceItem item)
    {
        return CreateActionSelector<IInvoiceItemActions<object>>(
            scope.Resolve<IInvoiceItemActions<TFormat>>(),
            new InvoiceItemSecurity(),
            i =>
            {
                i.Context = context;
                i.Invoice = new Invoice { CompanyID = context.CompanyID, InvoiceID = item.InvoiceID, Status = InvoiceStatus.Draft };
                i.Item = item;
            });
    }
}
```

And here is a snippet of code which actualy uses the framework for rendering action endpoints.

```
//usage example

IContext context = new FakeContext();
Invoice invoice = new Invoice { CompanyID = 1, InvoiceID = 1, Status = InvoiceStatus.Draft };
InvoiceItem invoiceItem = new InvoiceItem { InvoiceID = 1, InvoiceItemID = 1 };

var htmlEndpoint = new InvoicingEndpointFactory<HtmlEndpoint>(scope);

var forInvoice = htmlEndpoint.ForInvoice(context, invoice);

string html;
html = forInvoice.Action(a => a.Create).RenderAsButton("Add new invoice");
html = forInvoice.Action(a => a.Delete).RenderAsButton("Delete invoice");
html = forInvoice.Action(a => a.Publish).RenderAsButton("Publish invoice");

var forInvoiceItem = htmlEndpoint.ForInvoiceItem(context, invoiceItem);
html = forInvoiceItem.Action(a => a.RemoveVAT).RenderAsImage("minus.png");
html = forInvoiceItem.Action(a => a.SetPrice).RenderAsImage("dollar.png");
```

Am I over-engineering the solution?

Can you think of a use-case which cannot be covered gracefully with this approach?

Comment: `HtmlHelper`, editor templates, and the extensible model metadata provider would be the places to look. You can get to the stage where rendering an entire form for a model, including which parts are readonly, etc., is only a single line in your actual view file. I'm not sure what resources to recommend you, other than the "Build Your Own Application Framework with ASP.NET MVC 5" presentation on pluralsight, which unfortunately requires a paid subscription (though there may be a free trial).

Answer (score 2):

**General**

If you have something like

```
if (condition)
{
    return something;
}
else
{
   some more code
}
```

the `else` is not necessary.

So this

> ```
> public TFormat Action(Func<TCommonInterface, Func<object>> methodSelector)
> {
>     if (IsActionAllowed(methodSelector))
>     {
>         this.initalize(this.endpointFactory);
>         var generateActionInvocation = methodSelector(this.endpointFactory);
>         return (TFormat) generateActionInvocation();
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         return disabledEndpointFactory.Create();
>     }
> }
> ```

should be

```
public TFormat Action(Func<TCommonInterface, Func<object>> methodSelector)
{
    if (IsActionAllowed(methodSelector))
    {
        this.initalize(this.endpointFactory);
        var generateActionInvocation = methodSelector(this.endpointFactory);
        return (TFormat) generateActionInvocation();
    }

    return disabledEndpointFactory.Create();
}
```

**SecurityCheckResult**

IMHO, this class should be sealed and also the constructor should be private. The class has only two states `Allowed || !Allowed` which already are represented by the static fields `Ok` and `Fail`.